# Apply BLACK & WHITE color filters to Android WebView canvas Slow down its Scrolling Speed

Tags: android, canvas, webview, android-custom-view, colorfilter

I am using android WebView in my application to load my web pages and i want to assist my users to view WebView content also in black & white colors.
I applied color filters to WebView on its onDraw method:

```
public class WebViewInverterDummy extends WebView {


private Paint paint;
private ColorFilter cf;
private Rect inversionRect;
private Canvas cc;


private int NORMAL_MODE = 0;
private int BLACK_WHITE_MODE = 1;
public int WEB_VIEW_MODE = 0;
private int LAST_SELECTED_MODE = 0;


//    private Bitmap bitmap;

private ColorMatrix normalViewMatrix;
private ColorMatrix blackViewMatrix;

public WebViewInverterDummy(Context context) {
    super(context);
    intiFields();
    init();
    paint = new Paint();
    intBlackViewMatrix();
}
private void intiFields() {
    inversionRect = new Rect();
    cc = new Canvas();
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

     if (WEB_VIEW_MODE == NORMAL_MODE) {
        super.onDraw(c);
    } else {
        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            cc = new Canvas(bitmap);
        }
        super.onDraw(cc);
        init();
        c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }
}

private void init() {

    if (cf == null || WEB_VIEW_MODE != LAST_SELECTED_MODE) {
        if (WEB_VIEW_MODE == BLACK_WHITE_MODE) {
            if (blackViewMatrix == null)
                intBlackViewMatrix();
            cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(blackViewMatrix);
        }
    }
}


public void setWEB_VIEW_MODE(int mode) {
    LAST_SELECTED_MODE = WEB_VIEW_MODE;
    WEB_VIEW_MODE = mode;
}

public int getWebViewMode() {
    return WEB_VIEW_MODE;
}


private ColorMatrix intBlackViewMatrix() {
    // Black & white Mode
    float[] mx = new float[]{
            -1.0f, 0, 0, 0, 255, //red
            0, -1.0f, 0, 0, 255, //green
            0, 0, -1.0f, 0, 255, //blue
            0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0 //alpha
    };

    blackViewMatrix = new ColorMatrix(mx);
    blackViewMatrix.setSaturation(0);
    return blackViewMatrix;
}

}
```

i was successful to apply black & white color on WebView but the issue is that it slow down the scrolling speed of WebView. How i can optimized it and is there any way to directly apply color filters over canvas because drawing a bitmap over canvas slowing WebView speed.any suggestion to optimize it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your `ColorMatrixColorFilter` directly to the WebView in your main activity.

```
// Initialize `paint`.
Paint paint = new Paint();

// Setup the float array.
float[] mx = {
    -1.0f, 0, 0, 0, 255,  // red
    0, -1.0f, 0, 0, 255,  // green
    0, 0, -1.0f, 0, 255,  // blue
    0, 0, 0, -1.0f, 0     // alpha
};

// Set `paint` to use `mx` as the `ColorMatrixColorFilter`.
paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(mx));

// Apply `paint` to `webView`.
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, paint);
```

This is much more efficient than creating a bitmap and applying the `ColorMatrixColorFilter` to it `onDraw()`.